# Run independent operations between tidyverse pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyverse

Is there a way to run independent operations between `tidyverse`/`dplyr`'s pipes (`%>%`) without messing the main process? Let me share a fictional non-working example to explain myself better, using a `pass` function to run an operation between pipes.

```
temp <- 1 # Object that will change while using `pass` between pipes
some_df %>%
  mutate(x = "dummy1") %>%
  pass(temp <- temp + 1) %>% # Here we convert `temp` to 2
  mutate(y = "dummy2") %>%
  pass(temp <- temp + 1) # Here we convert `temp` to 3
```

This will be super useful for adding, for example, slide numbers dynamically on a PPT while using `officer` to build them. If I add a new slide somewhere in the middle, I'd have to change all of the posterior slides manually. I'm sure there must be a way! Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps use the `%T>%` (tee pipe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

temp <- 1
out <- 
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(x = "dummy1") %T>%
  {temp <<- temp + 1} %>% # Need to use `<<-`
  mutate(y = "dummy2") %T>%
  {temp <<- temp + 1}

out
temp
```

Output

```
> out
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb      x      y
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 dummy1 dummy2
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 dummy1 dummy2
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 dummy1 dummy2
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 dummy1 dummy2
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 dummy1 dummy2
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 dummy1 dummy2
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 dummy1 dummy2
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 dummy1 dummy2
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 dummy1 dummy2
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 dummy1 dummy2
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 dummy1 dummy2
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 dummy1 dummy2
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 dummy1 dummy2
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 dummy1 dummy2
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 dummy1 dummy2
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 dummy1 dummy2
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 dummy1 dummy2
18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 dummy1 dummy2
19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 dummy1 dummy2
20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 dummy1 dummy2
21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 dummy1 dummy2
22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 dummy1 dummy2
23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 dummy1 dummy2
24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 dummy1 dummy2
25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 dummy1 dummy2
26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 dummy1 dummy2
27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2 dummy1 dummy2
28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2 dummy1 dummy2
29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 dummy1 dummy2
30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 dummy1 dummy2
31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 dummy1 dummy2
32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 dummy1 dummy2
> temp
[1] 3
```

Comment: Wow, exactly what I needed. Thanks! I thought of a similar way without using `%T>%` but limited to my specific case: `plus_slide <- function(fun, slide) { slide <<- slide + 1; return(fun) }`